# Laravel: error while seeding the database (Array to string conversion)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-seeding

I'm trying to seed the database. Following the User example I create a Emploi (Job) seeder but I'm having an error.

seeding file

```
$factory->define(App\Emploi::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {

    return [
        'JOBURL' => $faker->name,
        'SALARYMAX' => '$50,000',
        'SALARYMIN' => '$40,000',
        'SALARYTYPE' => 'annual',
        'NAME' => $faker->words(5),
        'POSITION' => $faker->words(4),
        'JOBREF' => str_random(10),
        'JOB_SUMMARY' => $faker->text,
        'tweeted' => false,
        'POSTDATE' => $faker->dateTime(),
        'EXPIRYDATE' => $faker->dateTime(),
        'slug' => str_random(10),
    ];
});
```

exception

```
[ErrorException]
  Array to string conversion
```

output

```
 [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  Array to string conversion 
  (SQL: insert into `emplois` 

  (`JOBURL`, `SALARYMAX`, 
  `SALARYMIN`, `SALARYTYPE`, `NAME`, `POSITION`, 
  `JOBREF`, 
  `JOB_SUMMARY`, 
  `tweeted`, `
  POSTDATE`, `EXPIRYDATE`, `slug`, 
  `updated_at`, `created_at`) 
  values 
  (Lawson Boyer II, $50,000,
  $40,000, annual, rerum, voluptates, 
  LCw8d67S8w, 
  Nulla qui corporis sequi. 
  Eum nostrum culpa ut culpa velit. 
  Molestiae cumque doloremque et ex., 
  0, 
  1972-11-09 12:00:07, 1997-10-04 09:08:17, 6FxxCHFus6,
  2017-05-28 03:18:52, 2017-05-2  8 03:18:52)

  )
```

databaseSeeder

```
factory(App\Emploi::class, 50)->create();
```

Comment: Check the output for `$faker->words()`.

Comment: @WesleyPeeters thanks I'm having that array('leri', 'rednar', 'pratpu'). Can you post an answer so that I can vote up your answer

Comment: There you go! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Faker` library has a few methods that'll return an `array` instead of a `string`. What laravel is expecting here is a string. So, you could either use PHP's `implode` function to create a string, or swap out the entire `$faker->words()` method for `$faker->sentence()`. Here's the method signature:

`sentence($nbWords = 6, $variableNbWords = true)`

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for mentionning the API too! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

try `implode('',$faker->words(5))` instead of `$faker->words(5)` as laravel expects your value to be either numerical or string type.